# Download and use a publish settings file - On a Mac

Tags: azure

How do you create a publish settings file from Node.js on a Mac.

[This](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/azure.md) getting started guide says that I should:
Install and configure the Azure cross-platform command-line interface.

Following [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/#install) guide, the Node.js installed the Azure CLI ok. But it also says says "Download and use a publish settings file." 

Ok, but how when you dont have PowerShell?

Comment: Try `azure account download` from console. If that doesn't work, you can use this link to download publish settings file: https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index.

Comment: Thanks, I should have read further down :-)